# X-editable encoding success callback in data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I'm working with X-editable to create links that can be edited in place via ajax calls.

Everything on my page that is editable is created with the class editable, and uses the data-* parameters to pass values to x-editable.   Overall, this works, in that the update submits fine.

However, in the example below, the data-success function never calls - I never see the console log in this case.

```
<a href="#"  
class="editable" 
data-type="select" 
data-send="always" 
data-source='{"Windows 2000":"Windows 2000","Windows Server 2003":"Windows Server 2003","Windows Server 2008":"Windows Server 2008","Windows Server 2008 R2":"Windows Server 2008 R2","Windows Server 2012":"Windows Server 2012","Windows Server 2012 R2":"Windows Server 2012 R2","Other":"Other"}' data-name="Value"  
data-pk="1155"
data-display="function (value, response) { return false;}"
data-success="function (response, newValue) { console.log('success');}"
data-url="/attribute/updateField"
data-title="Title info">Windows Server 2008</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had asked the programmer of X-editable because I was trying the same thing and he replied that it's not possible to do so. His answer:

> I think it's impossible as data-attributes are parsed but not eval'ed as javascript.
>
> Also I think the better approach is to store js logic in js files, not in html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I found is this :

HTML :

```
<a href="#"  
class="editable" 
data-type="select" 
data-send="always" 
data-source='{"Windows 2000":"Windows 2000","Windows Server 2003":"Windows Server 2003","Windows Server 2008":"Windows Server 2008","Windows Server 2008 R2":"Windows Server 2008 R2","Windows Server 2012":"Windows Server 2012","Windows Server 2012 R2":"Windows Server 2012 R2","Other":"Other"}' data-name="Value"  
data-pk="1155"
data-eval-display="console.log('display', response, newValue);"
data-eval-success="console.log('success', response, newValue);"
data-url="/attribute/updateField"
data-title="Title info">Windows Server 2008</a>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('.editable').editable({
    display: function(response, newValue) {
        eval($(this).data('eval-display'));
    },
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        eval($(this).data('eval-success'));
    }
});
```